# Проблема при проверки на число

Tags: java

Создал консольный калькулятор, когда ввожу число ошибка `NumberFormatException`

```
  public int run() {
            int result = 0;
            double a = 0;
            double b = 0;
            char operation = ' ';
            System.out.println("Enter a first number");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

            while (validNumber(scanner.next())) {
                a = Double.parseDouble(scanner.nextLine());
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("Enter a last number");
            while (validNumber(scanner.nextLine())) {
                b = Double.parseDouble(scanner.nextLine());
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("Enter operation");
                operation = scanner.nextLine().charAt(0);
result = (int) calc(a, b, operation);
System.out.println(result);
            return result;
        }

    private boolean validNumber(String text) {
            try {
                Integer.parseInt(text);
                return true;
            } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Добавьте, что вводите, что хотите получить, и что получаете.

Comment: Вы проверяете Integer, а парсите Double, уверены, что это то, что вы хотите?

Comment: В первом `println` виводит Enter a first number, и ждет ввода. Ввожу число, и все обрьвается с ошибкой `NumberFormatException`

Comment: Komdosh, а как лучше сделать, в калькуляторе не будут с комой писать число.

Comment: Тип Integer для чисел.

Comment: С Integer, то же самое.

Comment: Вас не смущает, что при проверке Вы читаете из scanner, а потом при парсинге Вы опять читаете из scanner? Так нельзя. После проверки scanner пуст.

Comment: @Dejsving прав, вам нужно сначала записать число в строку, а потом, эту строку уже проверять и парсить.

Comment: Спасибо, ето сработало. Проблема еще осталась с циклом while, когда ввожу не число то оно все ровно вьходит из цикла. Почиму так ?

Comment: while (validNumber(scanner.next())) {

Comment: HasmikGaryaka, так тоже самое

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, что бы не было ошибки NumberFormatException в вашем коде требуется:

1. читать scanner в строку и работать с ней

   String input = scanner.next();

и дальше работаем с input.

Иначе после прочтения scanner-а функцией validNumber scanner будет пуст.

2. Что бы не прерывать while при "не числе"

Убрать или затащить break под if. Сейчас Вы независимо от парсинга применяете break. Естественно while прерывается.

Пример правильно while:

```
while (true)
{
    System.out.println("Enter a first number");
    String input = scanner.next();
    if (validNumber(input))
    {
        a = Double.parseDouble(input);
        break;
    }
    System.out.println("Not a correct input");
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, все почти работает. Когда просит ввести operation возникает ошибка 'StringIndexOutOfBoundsException' в 'operation = scanner.nextLine().charAt(0);'

Comment: поменяйте на operation = scanner.next().charAt(0); и будет Вам счастье. Тока я бы на место этого сканера на вашем месте вставил что-то посложнее, что бы отсеять неправильные знаки (нет ведь операции над числами h или j ...)

Answer (score 1):

Если просто нужна проверка на число, то можно сделать все проще(тут также учтено, что число может быть отрицательным)

```
private boolean validNumber(String text) {
  return text.matches("[-+]?\\d+");
}
```